# Duplicate Local Repo at different location so that changes made on Location 2 also apply to Location 1 locally (Windows)

Tags: windows, git, gitlab, symlink

I have a machine2 that has the resources I need to test a space consuming app. The issue is that machine has a firewalls that make it hard to pull and push commits to gitlab. Machine1 is where I do my development then I have to copy things over to machine2 to run the service

I wanted to see if there's a way to copy/duplicate/clone my local repo on machine1 to machine2 so that if i make changes in machine2, the changes will be reflected on machine1. So that all I need to do is to push commits from machine1 to the remote repo.

Is this possible? The 2 machines are on the same network and I can access both from each other in File Explorer

Answer (score 1):

Opinion based, but...

You can use [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net) which works fine even for git repositories. It can watch for the filesystem changes and copy automatically even large files and a lot of them as well. It has a [REST API](https://docs.syncthing.net/dev/rest.html) so you can manage it even remotely. I've used it for multiple and more than 200GB folders and runs smooth and without any significant issues. That's if you like more GUI-like approach or more scalable solution where you don't need to care about a lot of manual setup.

Alternatively, with more granular control, you can use [RSync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) if you want to sync only specific folder and [cron](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html) for scheduling the sync.

Alternatively, manually you can either create a git [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)(of remote) in two repositories (machine1 and machine2) and on each change you'll sync them with `git submodule update` or use a single repo and [mirroring](https://medium.com/cloud-native-the-gathering/how-to-mirror-copy-an-entire-existing-git-repository-into-a-new-one-3bb8faefad9e) a single git repo between multiple machines.

Comment: You've certainly given me a lot to look at lol. I appreciate the different options. Thanks!